# Ruby simple split and parse?

Tags: ruby, parsing, split

I have the following formula :

```
Revenue - Costs * (1 + Profitpercentage)
```

I want to parse it and keep only the significant strings, which requires eliminating : spaces, [-+*/=], and parentheses.

I came up with the following code :

```
p "Revenue - Costs * (1 + Profitpercentage)".split (/(\s|\.|\+|\-|\/|\*|\\)/)
```

but that only gave :

```
["Revenue", " ", "", "-", "", " ", "Costs", " ", "", "*", "", " ", "(1", " ", "", "+", "", " ", "Profitpercentage)"]
```

How can I sanitize my code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str = "Revenue - Costs * (1 + Profitpercentage)"
p str.scan(/[A-Za-z]+/)
# => ["Revenue", "Costs", "Profitpercentage"]
```

[`String#scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-scan)

Comment: omg, that was fast (I can only accept the answer in 7 minutes)... and it worked ;-) Thank you very much !